# discord.py rewrite on_message not existing command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

When I use the `!order` command the `Not existing command` message will be sent, how can I avoid that?

My code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.author
    def check(m):
        return m.channel == message.channel and m.author != client.user

    if message.content.startswith("!order"):
        await channel.send("in game name")
        in_game_name = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

        await channel.send("in game ID")
        in_game_ID = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

        await channel.send("cargo type")
        cargo_type = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

        await channel.send("cargo limit")
        cargo_limit = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

        await channel.send("storage")
        storage = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

        await channel.send("priority")
        priority = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    await client.process_commands(message)


@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("Not existing command!")
```

Comment: That's really odd.  Do you have another `on_message` event?

Comment: No, it's the only one

Comment: Is this the full `on_message` event?  For example, I don't see a `await client.process_commands(message)`, so commands shouldn't be called at all

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot about it, give me a sec

Comment: I updated the code, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just move the `process_commands` into an `else` block, so that it only runs if your `on_message` does not handle the command

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.author
    def check(m):
        return m.channel == message.channel and m.author != client.user

    if message.content.startswith("!order"):
        await channel.send("in game name")
        in_game_name = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

        await channel.send("in game ID")
        in_game_ID = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

        await channel.send("cargo type")
        cargo_type = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

        await channel.send("cargo limit")
        cargo_limit = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

        await channel.send("storage")
        storage = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

        await channel.send("priority")
        priority = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```